# Comunicar template com a view

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

Tenho um projeto django onde peço pro usuário digitar duas datas(inicial e final), e através delas eu faço uma consulta em um banco de dados externo, fazendo um input funciona, mas queria pegar essa informação do site e jogar ela na variável do views.py para assim tratar ela e depois gerar o resultado.

Segue imagem, quero colocar as datas nos lugares de texto e apertar o botao para gerar o grafico

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue minha views.py onde quero que as variáveis teste3 e teste4 sejam geradas pela requisição do template ao usuário

views.py

```
def index(request):
    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax.plot(teste3, teste4)
    #ax.bar(x_axis, y_axis, width=width_n, color=bar_color, align='center')
    ax.grid()
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    canvas.print_png(buf)
    response=HttpResponse(buf.getvalue(), content_type='image/png')
    return response
```

Template graficos_list.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block main %}

Edit


<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token  %}

    <input size="16" type="text" value="{{ descricao }}" class="form_datetime">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii' });
    </script>

    <input size="16" type="text" value="{{ descricao2 }}" class="form_datetime">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:ii' });
    </script>


    <a href="{% url 'tela_graficos' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Grafico</a>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Veja minha resposta, é só adaptar.

Answer (score 0):

Comparando o código com o título da pergunta, parece não fazer muito sentido para mim, que estou fora do seu contexto, então vou tentar responder me atentando exclusivamente no titulo da pergunta.

Para mostrar como a view "comunica" com a template, crio, na view, duas variáveis (`data1` e `data2`), inicialmente com o valor `None` para as duas e envio para a template onde apresento um form solicitando as duas datas e, em seguida, o codigo checa se ja foi enviado alguma vez para o form, se sim, o último envio é apresentado.

Para tornar as coisas fáceis, coloquei todo o codigo em apenas dois arquivos (`main.py` e `template1.html`), isto não é usual em django, mas faço comentários no código de onde cada parte deveria estar por convenção (as que eu lembrei).

Copie o conteudo do tópico abaixo "main.py" para um arquivo `.py` e o do tópico "template1.html" obrigatoriamente para um arquivo com esse nome.

main.py

```
# Configurações do django, aqui configura-se o projeto django, desde conexoes 
# com banco de dados até recursos estaticos e funcionalidades de internacionalização
# Novamente, no 'mundo real', essas configuracoes estariam em um arquivo settings.py
from django.conf import settings
import os
ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
settings.configure(
    DEBUG=True,
    SECRET_KEY = '0uarl&=3a$o1*0wk-5s@x6@d*0%r576h0&@f65+09ebtkv3jtd',
    ROOT_URLCONF=__name__,
    MIDDLEWARE = (
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ),
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [ROOT]
        }
    ]
)

# No mundo real esse codigo estaria em um arquivo views.py
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render 
def index(request):

    data1 = None
    data2 = None

    if request.method=='POST':
        data1 = request.POST['data1']
        data2 = request.POST['data2']
        # Faça aqui o que vc quiser com data1 e data2, aqui vou apenas enviar de volta ao site

    return render(request, 'template1.html', {'data1': data1, 'data2': data2})

# Para conectar a view à estrutura do site é preciso associa-la a uma URL
# No mundo real esse codigo estaria em um arquivo urls.py
from django.urls import include, path
urlpatterns = (
    path('', index),
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

template1.html

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="data1">Data Inicial:</label>
    <input id="data1" type="date" name="data1" value="" /><br>
    <label for="data2">Data Final:</label>
    <input id="data2" type="date" name="data2" value="" /><br>
    <input type="submit">

    {% if data1 != None %}
        <br><br>
        <p>
            Sua última digitação:<br>
            Data Inicial: {{data1}}<br>
            Data Final: {{data2}}<br>
        </p>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

rode o `.py`  pela linha de comando, supondo que vc tenha nomeado o arquivo de `main.py`, rode-o assim:

```
python main.py runserver
```

Aponte seu browse para http://127.0.0.1:8000/ e vc verá o site solicitando duas datas, inicial e a final, a partir do momento que vc fizer a digitação, o site informará sempre a ultima entrada.

Saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: cara, ajudou muito, mas um pequeno detalhe, quando clico no botao enviar, ele da um erro: 'MultiValueDictKeyError at /polls/' polls seria o meu app para essa views e esse template

Comment: Não estou vendo o botão "enviar" no seu codigo.

Comment: eu tinha implementado do seu, mas ja arrumei, uma dúvida só, no seu código, a varíavel data1 pode ser trata na view? ou só pode ficar com o valor none?

Comment: Veja o meu comentário no codigo `# Faça aqui o que vc quiser com data1 e data2 ...`, `None` é o valor inicial.

Comment: sim, eu entendi isso, mas ele votla o valor pra minha views, eu mexo nele e vira um template com um grafico, depois de tratar tudo, eu clicar no botao grafico, ele gera a tela certa?

Comment: Perae... no exemplo, data1 é um variavel do tipo data, vc quer transformar uma variável do tipo data em uma template com um grafico? Não entendi.

Comment: eu pego a variavel tipo da data e jogo como a data para consulta no banco, ai através do resultado gerado nessa consulta eu faço um gráfico e jogo em um template, a dúvida é, essa informação do tipo data passada pelo usuário é recebida na views e assim pode ser usada para essa consulta?

Comment: Sim, pegue meu exemplo e onde esta o comentário faça alguns testes com as 2 variaveis, vc pode fazer um print, consultar um banco que traga os resultados que quiser e enviar para a template em um dicionario, por exemplo. Na template vc pode manipular esses dados e plotar um grafico se quiiser, agora... Se não domina ainda esses conceitos, sugiro estudar o django, comece pelo [tutorial da documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/intro/tutorial01/), totalmente de gratis, basta se dedicar.

Comment: show, to com outros problemas aqui nada a ve com o post, mas resolvendo eles eu testo e te falo aqui