# Passar argumentos da view para o form Django

Tags: python, django

Olá, boa noite!

Eu estou fazendo uma aplicação de perguntas e respostas no django e tenho basicamente esses models:

App de múltipla escolha:

```
class MCQuestao(Questao):

    def checar_correta(self, ans):
        answer = Alternativa.objects.get(id=ans)

        if answer.correta is True:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def pegar_questoes(self):
        return Alternativa.objects.filter(questao=self)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Questão múltipla escolha'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Questões múltiplas escolhas'

class Alternativa(models.Model):
    questao = models.ForeignKey(MCQuestao, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    resposta = models.TextField()
    fundteorico = models.TextField()
    correta = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.resposta

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Alternativa"
        verbose_name_plural = "Alternativas"
```

App de questões:

```
class Situacao(models.Model):
    enunciado = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True)
    certificado = models.ManyToManyField(Certificado)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}...'.format(self.enunciado[:80])

    def get_resolucao(self):
        return self.resolucao

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Situação" 
        verbose_name_plural = "Situações"

class Resolucao(models.Model):
    resolucao = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
    situacao = models.OneToOneField(Situacao, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.resolucao

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Resolução"
        verbose_name_plural = "Situações"

class Questao(models.Model):
    subdominio = models.ManyToManyField(SubDominio)
    resolucao = models.ForeignKey(Resolucao, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='')
    questao = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.questao

    objects = InheritanceManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Questão"
        verbose_name_plural = "Questões"
        ordering = ['subdominio__name']
```

E na minha view eu passo basicamente um argumento que eu uso pra verificar a questão (um id) e a partir dele eu pego a questão, após pego a questão eu passo ela como argumento e puxo as alternativas. Eu gostaria de passar essas informações pra o form, pra eu poder fazer o tratamento do form, verificar se uma questão é correta, etc.

Código da view pergunta:

```
def pergunta(request, slug, id):

    certificacao = get_object_or_404(Certificacao, slug=slug)
    situacao = Situacao.objects.get(certificado__id=id)
    resolucao = Resolucao.objects.get(situacao=situacao)
    questao = Questao.objects.get(resolucao=resolucao)
    alternativa = Alternativa.objects.filter(questao=questao)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestaoForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponse('Parabéns! Acertou!')

    else:
        form = QuestaoForm()

    return render(request, 'certificacoes/pergunta.html', {'form': form})
```

Gostaria de mostrar as informações basicamente assim, aí ao clicar no submit eu faria a verificação do booleano se a questão estaria correta e tal, porém tô a dias parado nisso e não tenho ideia de como solucionar. Obrigado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Respondi uma pergunta identica a essa, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/367596/comunicar-template-com-a-view/367624#367624). Se quer manter essa pergunta, mostre o codigo da view e da template, para dar subsidios para quem quiser ajudar.

Comment: Editei com a view, Sidon. Obrigado e vou dar uma lida no seu post.

Comment: Leia, mas dê ctrl-c/ctrl-v no codigo (são apenas 2 arquivos minimos) e  execute no seu ambiente, como eu sugiro, e vc vai entender, qq duvida pergunte la.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu fiz algo parecido, eu sobre escrevi o metodo init do formulário. Na hora de instanciar o formulário eu passo os parâmetros que quero:

```
form = QualquerForm(request.POST,var1='ola mundo')
```

Agora sobre escrevendo o método do formulário:

```
class QualquerForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self.var1 = kwargs.get('var1',None)
        super(QualquerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Assim eu posso acessar em qualquer método a variável passada assim:

```
self.var1
```